# Perform a different regular expression for each column in a tab delimited file

Tags: linux, perl, bash, unix

I found myself writing PERL for the first time in about 8 years and I am having difficulties with something that should be easy.  Here is the basic premise:

A file containing a hundred or so fields 10 of which have incorrect data (the O's are 0's)

```
A   B   C   D    E  F   ... 
br0wn   red   1278076   0range   "20 tr0ut"   123 ...
Green   0range   90876   Yell0w   "18 Salm0n"   456   ...
```

I am trying to write the program to split the fields and then allow me to run a regex on field A to replace 0 with O but not replace 0 with O for column C and so on I have the additional problem of needing to possibly run an alternate regex for column E for instance.

I was able to split all the fields in a record by the /t.  I am having an issue formatting my command to go over each field and run a specific regex based on the field it is.

Any help would be appreciated and I will Paypal you 10 dollars for a beverage of your choice if you solve it.

Comment: How do you want to handle column E? `20 tr0ut`

Comment: That is just it, I thought I would only translate 0 to O where not next two other numbers.  I would think that would catch most of them

Answer (score 1):

Using a csv parser such as [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) is not complicated. Something like this might suffice:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        sep_char    => "\t",
        binary      => 1,
        eol         => $/,
});
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA)) {
    tr/0/o/ for @{$row}[0, 1, 3];            # replace in cols A, B and D
    s/(?<!\d)0(?!\d)/o/g for @{$row}[4];     # replace in col E
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row);              # print the result
}


__DATA__
A   B   C   D   E   F
br0wn   red 1278076 0range  "20 tr0ut"  123
Green   0range  90876   Yell0w  "18 Salm0n" 456
```

**Output:**

```
A       B       C       D       E       F
brown   red     1278076 orange  "20 trout"      123
Green   orange  90876   Yellow  "18 Salmon"     456
```

Note that I handled your mixed string (column E) with a simplistic regex instead of transliteration (global replace), and it simply does not replace zeroes which are next to numbers, which will fail for certain numbers, such as `20.0` or `0`.

**Update:**

If you want to do the substitutions based on column *names* instead of position, things get a bit more complicated. However, `Text::CSV` can handle it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my @pure_text   = qw(A B D);
my @mixed       = qw(E);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        sep_char    => "\t",
        binary      => 1,
        eol     => $/,
});

my $cols = $csv->getline(*DATA);              # read column names
$csv->print(*STDOUT, $cols);
$csv->column_names($cols);                    # set column names

while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr(*DATA)) {   # hash ref instead of array ref
    tr/0/o/ for @{$row}{@pure_text};          # substitution on hash slice
    s/(?<!\d)0(?!\d)/o/g for @{$row}{@mixed};
    my @row = @{$row}{@$cols};                # make temp array for printing
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, \@row);
}


__DATA__
A   B   C   D   E   F
br0wn   red 1278076 0range  "20 tr0ut"  123
Green   0range  90876   Yell0w  "18 Salm0n" 456
```

This code is a standalone for demonstration. To try the code on a file, change `*DATA` to `*STDIN` and use the script as follows:

```
perl script.pl < input.csv
```

Comment: So looks like it might just do the trick, The output prints " characters around the results or is that just a replacement of the tab character?  I am going to build my arrays to seperate the fields and give it a real run.  I think I owe you a paypal.

Comment: The csv module adds quotes when they are needed, not sure what you are referring to. Hey, that'd be the first money I make coding perl. :)

Comment: So here is a weird one, I tried running it against a real file and I got 30 records in and it broke. I think it is not parsing on tab correctly There is a long string with multiple quotes in the string that seems to break it.  anyway I can improve the sorting of fields on tab?

Comment: I took a look around and I discovered auto_diag, the error is CSV_PP ERROR: 2034 - EIF - Loose unescaped quote  which is indeed what I suspected.  sadly changing to explicitly call as utf8 does not solve it.  I think I am closer though

Comment: I think I found it allow_loose_quotes,

Comment: Yes, this module can take some tweaking, especially with non-uniform input. It can be a good idea to simply read through the file and check for input errors, i.e. print the lines that fail to a separate file to see what kind of edge cases require handling.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Simply add the column names into the array in the `BEGIN` block. In the example below, only columns A, C and E will be modified. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"

    a["A"]
    a["C"]
    a["E"]
}

{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {

        if ($i in a && NR==1) {
            b[i]
        }

        else if (i in b) {
            $i = gensub(/(^|[^0-9])0([^0-9]|$)/,"\\1o\\2", "g", $i)
        }
    }
}1
```

Tab separated results:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   ... 
brown   red 1278076 0range  "20 trout"  123 ...
Green   0range  90876   Yell0w  "18 Salmon" 456 ...
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"; a["A"]; a["C"]; a["E"] } { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i in a && NR==1) b[i]; else if (i in b) $i = gensub(/(^|[^0-9])0([^0-9]|$)/,"\\1o\\2", "g", $i) } }1' file
```

Comment: Wow quick response,  So I was thinking of doing it with awk but I wanted to be able to make different rules based on the field name like A,B and not by position of the field.  I no the name will stay the same not neccesarily the field location

Comment: @user2041477 Are you now adding the requirement that field names, and not positions, should be used?

Comment: Field names would be optimal,  Sorry my system does not have TEXT::CSV I am putting it in my local library.

Comment: @user2041477 I have updated my answer. You should mention all such restrictions right away. I don't think you'll easily keep track of column names unless you use a csv parser, though.

Comment: @user2041477: I've updated my answer to include the updated requirements. It should now work for you correctly. If the regex is sub-optimal, you should be able to modify it to suit your needs fairly easily. If you need, you can read more about awk's string functions [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of subroutines, something like:

```
my @fixer;
$fixer[0] = sub { $_[0] =~ s/0/o/; };
my @fields = split /\t/, $input;
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#fields; $i++) {
   $fixer[$i]->($fields[$i]) if defined $fixer[$i];
}
```

Comment: So maybe I am not reading this correctly, but here goes my translation,  the fixer array has a subroutine and I could add aditional subroutines to it.  I then split the fields and for each field run the field fixer?  $fixer[$i]->($fields[$i]) if defined $fixer[$i];

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use Perl in 'autosplit' mode:

```
perl -a -p -F"\t" \
     -e '$F[0] =~ s/0/o/g;
         $F[1] =~ s/0/O/g;
         $F[3] =~ s/0/o/g;
         $F[4] =~ s/(\D)0(\D)/\1o\2/g;  # Or other more complex regex
         # ...                          # Other fields can be edited
         $_ = join("\t", @F);           # Reassign fields to $_
        ' data-file
```

The regex for `$F[4]` changes '20 tr0ut' into '20 trout'; you can make it more complex if you need.

Output on sample data:

```
A       B       C       D       E       F       ...
brown   red     1278076 orange  "20 trout"      123     ...
Green   Orange  90876   Yellow  "18 Salmon"     456     ...
```

This does assume a strictly tab-separated data file.  The quoted strings containing spaces complicate things if you do not have strictly tab-separated data; at that point, Text::CSV is attractive for reading the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with a simple configuration using array references and/or subroutines, then the substitutions happening later:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @subst = ([
  ['this', 'that'],
  ['O', 1],
],[
  ['foo', 'boo'],
  sub {s/a.*//},
]);

sub mk_subst {
  my $list = shift;
  my ($this, $that) = eval { @$list };
  return $list unless defined $this;
  sub { s/\Q$this/$that/ };
}

my @all;
for my $set (@subst) {
  my @list = eval { @$set };
  unless (@list) {
    push @all, [ sub {} ];
    next;
  }
  my @re;
  for my $s (@list) {
    push @re, mk_subst($s);
  }
  push @all, \@re;
}

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @list = split /\t/, $_, -1;
  for my $i (0..$#list) {
    for ($list[$i]) {
      for my $funcs ($all[$i]) {
        for my $f (@$funcs) {
          $f->();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  print join("\t", @list), "\n";
}

__DATA__
thisO   fooabca1234
abc 123fooabca1234
```

Comment: I tried this one and it seems to be printing 2 records for every item

Comment: That's because I have two print statements in the loop...a before and after transformation...was debugging, I'm taking the first print out.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F -lane 'for(@F){$_=~s/0/o/g if(/0/ && /[a-zA-Z]+/);} print "@F"' your_file
```

Tested below

```
> cat temp
br0wn   red   1278076   0range   "20 tr0ut"   123 ...
Green   0range   90876   Yell0w   "18 Salm0n"   456   ...

> perl -F -lane 'for(@F){$_=~s/0/o/g if(/0/ && /[a-zA-Z]+/);} print "@F"' temp
brown red 1278076 orange "20 trout" 123 ...
Green orange 90876 Yellow "18 Salmon" 456 ...
>
```