# REGEX replacing 0 with o if it is in the first two positions in a field

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I am stumbling on a problem That I thought would be easy

I have a fields with `aaa a0a 0a0` that I need to change to `aaa aoa oa0`

the regex I have is changing `a0a` to `ooa` or `0a0` to `oo0`

Comment: Similar to [Perform a different regular expression for each column in a tab delimited file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698706/perform-a-different-regular-expression-for-each-column-in-a-tab-delimited-file/).

Comment: I very much like choroba's idea in a refined version: `substr($field, 0, 2) =~ tr/0/o/`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to put all work into one regex.  Do it in two different regexes for readability.

```
s/^0/o/;       # Change 0 to o in first column
s/^(.)0/$1o/;  # Change 0 to o in second column
```

What could be clearer than that?

Remember, you're not coding for Today You, you're coding for Tomorrow You and Tomorrow Other People.

Comment: `s/^(.)0/$1o/;` can be written `s/^.\K0/o/;`

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses a substring as a lvalue. If you want to turn `00a` to `ooa`, add `/g` to the substitution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ar = qw/aaa a0a 0a0 00a/;
for my $field (@ar) {
    substr($field, 0, 2) =~ s/0/o/;  # Only applied to the substring!
    print "$field\n";
}
```

Comment: It seems to me this is way too complicated for such a simple task

Comment: +1 Very cool, but perhaps impractical. You know you do not have to go over a reference to do it, just do `substr($field,0,2) =~ s/0/o/g`.

Comment: @choroba You should use either `s/0/o/g` or `tr/0/o/` though.

Comment: @TLP: The specification is a bit unclear on this. That's why added the last field (and I mentioned the possibility).

Comment: @choroba Ah, I see. Yes, it is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an expression like:

```
s/\b0|(?<=\b\S)0/o/g;
```

Example:

```
perl -E "$_='aaa a0a 0a0 000'; say; s/\b0|(?<=\b\S)0/o/g; say"
```

Output:

```
aaa a0a 0a0 000
aaa aoa oa0 oo0
```

Comment: I was about to say `s/(?:(?<=\b)|(?<=\b.))0/o/g` but I knew there had to be a simpler form, and there you have it

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should do, but I am little rusty on my regex so apologies if that's not what you are looking for, all those should work (I'm sure there is plenty more ways to achieve this)

```
# replace all zeros providing they are followed by an aplhanumeric character
s/0(?=\w)/o/g; 

# same as the above except reverted, replace zeros if not followed by space
s/0(?!\s)/o/g; 

# replace 0 followed by word non-boundary
s/0\B/o/g;
```